# How to press ESC only once to close suggestions list and exit insert mode

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

When using CoC.nvim's suggestion list, I often find myself pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice to return to normal mode - once for cancelling CoC's list session and once to actually exit insert mode. I find that extraneous (and noisy, considering I'm using a clicky mechanical keyboard in an open office).

I checked CoC's documentation but could not find anything that would solve this with configuration.

What is a good, maintainable way of having <kbd>Esc</kbd> close CoC's list session and exit insert mode with one press?

Comment: That's weird what you describe here seems to be the default behavior for me (in neovim and vim both with coc completion or with the default completion). Do you use a custom configuration to show coc completions or do you use the built-in pop up menu?

Comment: @statox Nope, the only thing I have in my coc-settings.json file is the configuration for a language server. Maybe I'll try to do a fresh install of CoC to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was another plugin causing the interference: [townk/vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose). After uninstalling it, the issue went away.

I am now using [jiangmiao/auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) without problems.